# Testing the User Model with Rspec, Devise, and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, factory-bot

I think there is a problem with my user factory being built. I'm getting an error saying that the password cannot be blank, but it's clearly set in my factories.rb. Does anyone see anything that I may be missing? Or a reason as to why the spec is failing? I do a very similar thing for one of my other models, and it seems to be successful. I'm not sure if the error is being caused by devise or not.

#### Rspec Error

```
User should create a new instance of a user given valid attributes
Failure/Error: User.create!(@user.attributes)
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
  Validation failed: Password can't be blank
# ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

#### Factories.rb

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.name                   "Test User"
  user.email                  "user@example.com"
  user.password               "password"
  user.password_confirmation  "password"
end
```

#### user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory.build(:user)
  end

  it "should create a new instance of a user given valid attributes" do
    User.create!(@user.attributes)
  end
end
```

#### user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Factory Girl, this create attributes:

```
@user_attr = Factory.attributes_for(:user)
```

And this create a new instance:

```
@user = Factory(:user)
```

So change the above and try:

```
User.create!(@user_attr)
```

In depth, what you're trying to do fails because:

- you were creating a new unsaved instance
- password is a virtual attribute
- the attributes of the instance do not contain the virtual attributes (I guess)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't seem to work. I do want to build attributes though I think, so that I can easily manipulate @user for future tests using @user.attributes.merge(:name => "Whatever"). That's why I was trying User.create!(@user.attributes).

I tried doing User.create!(@user) but it failed, this time saying that the Email was blank, and the Password was blank.

Comment: That worked. That's very interesting. I guess what confuses me now is that I'm not sure why my other one seems to work. I have a "Role" model, and I do the same thing, using @role = Factory.build(:role), and Role.create!(@role.attributes)

And it seems to pass. Interesting. Thank you sir.

Comment: Your test here failed because of the virtual attributes

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the term virtual attributes. Is that related to devise?

Comment: No at all, they are just a mean to an end: basically, you have no password_confirmation column in your model. See here for more info: http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes

Comment: Thanks apneadiving, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest approach IMO:

```
FactoryGirl.modify do
  factory :user do
    after(:build) { |u| u.password_confirmation = u.password = ... }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

One tip that did the work for me. I was using `FactoryGirl.create(:user)` which didn't work. Changed it to this:

```
user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
user.password = "123456"
user.save
post :login, {:email => user.email, :password => "123456"}
# do other stuff with logged in user
```

This maybe is because 'password' is a virtual field. Hope this could hint someone.